excel vba - get dynamic array formula range from cell address
I'm new to Excel VBA and was wondering if there is a way to retrieve the entire range of a dynamic array table (like a CSE array) given an address of a specific cell that is known to be inside that range ?
say I have a dynamic array table given an address of a single cell how can I determine the range of the entire table ?

Range("yourcell").SpillParent.SpillingToRange I think. Though this is for dynamic array formulas that spill, so not CSE formulas

Recognizing that spill doesn't work for me, I have used end() in different capacities to define a range.  E.g., currentcell.end(xlToRight).column - currentCell.Column tells you the range of contiguous cells.  Not a fan of the next, but Used Range may also support, but is extremely finnicky.  I would say data dictates the best approach, and if spill techniques cause issues for you, there can be alternatives.

For a given cell c check cells above until the formula changes, then left to find the top-left corner of the range.  Then do the same to find the bottom-right.  You can wrap that up in a function.

thanks for the suggestions. Range("yourcell").SpillParent.SpillingToRange seems to work however I also need to get the range when a SPILL ERROR occurs. is this possible ?

For a given cell c check cells above until the formula changes, then move left to find the top-left corner of the range. Then do the same to find the bottom-right corner. You can wrap that up in a function.
Assuming:

selected cell is part of a formula array range
no surrounding cells are part of a separate array which shares the same formula

Sub Tester()
    Debug.Print ArrayRange(Selection).Address
End Sub

Function FormulaArrayRange(c As Range) As Range
    Dim f, c2 As Range
    f = c.FormulaArray
    Set c2 = c
    'check up and left
    Do While c.offset(-1).FormulaArray = f: Set c = c.offset(-1): Loop
    Do While c.offset(0, -1).FormulaArray = f: Set c = c.offset(0, -1): Loop
    'check down and right
    Do While c2.offset(1).FormulaArray = f: Set c2 = c2.offset(1): Loop
    Do While c2.offset(0, 1).FormulaArray = f: Set c2 = c2.offset(0, 1): Loop
    Set ArrayRange = c.Parent.Range(c, c2) 'create range from top-left and bottom-right
End Function

